# Making a List Content Type visible via CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I generally do all of my programmatic stuff using SharePoint PNP, but adding a content type to a list in a subsite does not show the content type as visible on the new button.

Because of this, I am looking to show it via code. I don't usually do this so looking for some help. So far I have this:

```
Connect-PnpOnline -Url $url -Credentials $creds
$ctx = Get-PnpContext
$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("My List Name")
$ctx.Load($List)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$ct = Get-PnpContentType -List "My List Name" -Identity "My Content Type Name"
$ctid = $ct.id.StringValue
```

This is where I get stuck. Can't really find anything that does what I am trying to do. Basically I want to just do `$contentType.Hidden = $false`.

Thanks.

This is what I want: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.contenttype.hidden.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I add the content type to the list in the subsite by the PnPPowerShell Add-PnPContentTypeToList, it will show when clicking on new button. The content type “item1” has been created in the site content type.

My PnP code as below:

```
$siteUrl="https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/t3"
Connect-PnPOnline -url $siteUrl
Add-PnPContentTypeToList -List "list1" -ContentType "item1"
```

[image]

[image]
And you also could add content type to list by PowerShell script in the article below.

Add content type to an SharePoint Online list.

http://www.sharepointfire.com/2016/01/add-content-type-sharepoint-online-list-powershell/

Comment: And I'm seeing something similar to this https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1101

Comment: Hidden doesnt fix my problem. Closing the question.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to Load the list object and then Content Type within the list. I have tried below code and it is working for me.

http://codesharepoint.com/csom/set-list-content-type-read-only-in-sharepoint-using-csom

In the code, instead of **ReadOnly = true** attribute, you can pass **Hidden = false**